# Nextcloud client-building requires P12_KEY_PASSWORD

Tags: openssl, signing, nextcloud, p12

I am currently trying to build my own Nextcloud Desktop Client with my own logo and disabled updates, Since I have no experience in Desktop Application (I'm a support, with beginner experience at web development), I am following the guide from here

https://github.com/nextcloud/client-building/

I've installed all of the requirement, and tried to test build it with

```
TEST_RUN=1 ./build.bat
```

It ran nicely until I encounter an error that says

```
"* USE_CODE_SIGNING=1"
"Missing environment variable: P12_KEY_PASSWORD"
"*** Build FAILED: installer-collect Release Win64 (single-build-installer-collect.bat)"
"***** Build FAILED (build.bat)"
```

Then, I've read in the Issues page of the client-building repo and one of the member said

> This is to sign the binary. You'll need to get your own if you want to sign it.

I have a very small experience in OpenSSL and signing. I've tried to search on how to generate the key password but haven't found any answers regarding how to and how to implement the 'key password' to the code, are there any place I should start reading / get into into understanding on how this works and fix the problem? I've thought of skipping the code signing but I'm afraid it'll messed up with the end product and makes the new Nextcloud Client unable to connect to my server.

Answer (score 0):

There is a P12_KEY_PASSWORD parameter in the defaults.inc.bat file that you should set to fix the problem.

Regards